# Editing/Inserting/Deleting with Dynamically created controls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

My goal is to essentially create a list of GridViews (each one maps to a table) with edit, delete, and insert capability. (The insert capability could be done with template field in the footer.)

I have a gridview nested within a repeater and each one is created dynamically. I have populated the gridview successfully with bound fields (although I need to eventually change this to template fields to get dropdownlists and for inserting). However, now that I'm thinking about edit/delete/insert, I'm wondering if there is a better way.

What is the best way to do what I'm trying to do? I feel like I'm making it more difficult than it should be and GridView might not be the best control. Should I just use nested repeaters? Use a ListView inside of a repeater?

If you think there is a better way of doing this, please provide suggestions/examples. Thanks!

Current code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="FormRepeater" DataSourceID="sdsRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="FormID" Value='<%# Bind("FormID") %>' runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="tablename" Value='<%# Bind("TableName") %>' runat="server" />
        <div class="gvHeader2">
            <div class="gvHeader">
                <asp:Label ID="lblFormName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FormName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="EditFormImage">
            </div>
            <div class="CreateFormLink">
                <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkCreateForm" runat="server">
                    Create New
                </asp:HyperLink>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="gv">
        <asp:GridView ID="gvForms" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsGVForms" 
            DataKeyNames="FormDataID"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            AutoGenerateEditButton="true"
            OnRowEditing="GV_RowEditing"
            OnRowCommand="GV_RowCommand"
        >
            <Columns>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

        </div>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

    Private Sub FormRepeater_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles FormRepeater.ItemDataBound

    Dim TableName As String = CType(e.Item.FindControl("tablename"), HiddenField).Value
    Dim FormID As Integer = CType(e.Item.FindControl("FormID"), HiddenField).Value
    Dim ProductID As Integer = Page.RouteData.Values("ProductID")
    Dim sdsForms As SqlDataSource = CType(e.Item.FindControl("sdsGVForms"), SqlDataSource)
    Dim gvForms As WebControls.GridView = CType(e.Item.FindControl("gvForms"), GridView)
    Dim dt As DataTable = F.GetFormFieldsToDisplayInList(FormID)
    For Each r As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim bfield As BoundField = New BoundField
        bfield.DataField = r(0)
        bfield.HeaderText = r(1)
        gvForms.Columns.Add(bfield)
        FieldList.Add(r(0))

    Next
    sdsForms.SelectCommand = "SQL Query..."
    gvForms.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your requirements, it's hard to say.

However, there is a grid here that compares ListView, GridView, DataList and the Repeater you may find helpful.

http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2008/09/06/comparing-listview-with-gridview-datalist-and-repeater.aspx

Comment: I decided to go another route for simplicity purposes for now, but I think you're right. If I tackle this again, I should use a ListView instead of a GridView. Thanks!